# Basic use of TranslationServiceProvider in Silex

Tags: translation, silex

I'm trying to use the Silex TranslationServiceProvider in the most straighforward way i.e.

```php
<?php
// web/index.php
require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new Silex\Application();

$app->register(new Silex\Provider\TranslationServiceProvider(), array(
  'locale'            => 'fr',
  'locale_fallbacks'  => array('en')
));

$app['translator.domains'] = array(
  'messages' => array(
    'en' => array('message_1' => 'Hello!'),
    'fr' => array('message_1' => 'Bonjour')
));

echo $app['translator']->trans('message_1'); 
// I get 'Hello!' (why ?)
```

It seems that the `'locale' => 'fr'` line when initializing the TranslationServiceProvider is not taken into account and that the only parameter that counts is `locale_fallbacks` (when I change locale_fallbacks to `'fr'`, the message is displayed in french)

Is there something very simple I am missing here ?

Thanks in advance

**Edit**

When I use the the `setLocale` function, it still doesn't work and seems to override the `locale_fallbacks`:

```php
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\TranslationServiceProvider(), array(
  'locale_fallbacks'  => array('en')
));

$app['translator']->setLocale('fr');
echo $app['translator']->getLocale(); // returns 'fr' as expected

$app['translator.domains'] = array(
  'messages' => array(
    'en' => array('message_1' => 'Hello!'),
    'fr' => array('message_1' => 'Bonjour')
));

echo $app['translator']->trans('message_1');
// now returns 'message_1' (??)
```

What's wrong with the way I use the provider ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must set the locale, otherwise the fallback is used:

```
$app['translator']->setLocale('fr');
```

I'm setting the locale in a `$app->before()` handler:

```
$app->before(function(Request $request) use ($app) {
  // default language
  $locale = 'en';
  // quick and dirty ... try to detect the favorised language - to be improved!
  if (!is_null($request->server->get('HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'))) {
    $langs = array();
    // break up string into pieces (languages and q factors)
    preg_match_all('/([a-z]{1,8}(-[a-z]{1,8})?)\s*(;\s*q\s*=\s*(1|0\.[0-9]+))?/i',
      $request->server->get('HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'), $lang_parse);
    if (count($lang_parse[1]) > 0) {
        foreach ($lang_parse[1] as $lang) {
            if (false === (strpos($lang, '-'))) {
                // only the country sign like 'de'
                $locale = strtolower($lang);
            } else {
                // perhaps something like 'de-DE'
                $locale = strtolower(substr($lang, 0, strpos($lang, '-')));
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    $app['translator']->setLocale($locale);
    $app['monolog']->addDebug('Set locale to '.$locale);
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply Ralf. I'has tried that but it still doesn't take it into account. The strange thing is that, when I do that, the fallback doesn't event work and the translation service returns 'message_1' (???). I've updated my question accordingly

Comment: Hmm, I can't see anything wrong ... 8-( ... is your code available at github or anywhere else?

Comment: My code can't be more  simple : I have a web/index.php file and a composer.json. You'll find them here : https://gist.github.com/marivaudage/0fc2771c0a06b61b268e

Comment: You must place `setLocale()` *after* the definition of the `translator.domains`, that's all.

Answer (score 1):

Two remarks on Ralf’s answer:

1. Almost all that is done in the before() middleware in unnecessary, as the Request class provides a convenience method for determining the “best” language based on the “Accept-Language” header. So basically, nothing more than this is required:

   ```
   $app->before(
       function (Request $request) use ($app) {
           $app['translator']->setLocale($request->getPreferredLanguage(['en', 'fr']));
       }
   );
   ```
2. Silex uses the “magic” variable “{_locale}” in a route’s definition to set the locale accordingly. This means you do neither need to declare the locale when instantiating `TranslationServiceProvider`, nor call `setLocale()`,  but simply declare the route like this:

   ```
   $app->get('/{_locale}/path', ...);
   ```

Now, Twig and `$app['translator']` (inside the Closure or controller method) will automatically be set to the correct locale.